# Regex to capture classes in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to capture all the possible HTML classes of a file.

Let's take this content as an example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="bg-secondary-7 -mx-5 p-5 hover:bg-secondary-8"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const isTrue = 1 === 1;

    const z = `hello ${isTrue ? "is-true" : "is-false"}`;
  </script>
</html>
```

It should match:

- `bg-secondary-7`
- `-mx-5`
- `p-5`
- `hover:bg-secondary-8`
- `hello`
- `is-true`
- `is-false`

I've tried this so far:

```
/(["'`])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/g
```

It matches:

- `bg-secondary-7 -mx-5 p-5 hover:bg-secondary-8`
- `hello ${isTrue ? "is-true" : "is-false"}`

Then I can separate the strings using `string.split(' ')`.

The problem is that for template literals the expressions are not being matched: `"is-true"` and `"is-false"` are not being matched.

What can be a good solution for this?

Edit:

The goal is to take an HTML or JS file and get all the possible HTML classes that can be used, it's easy from the HTML because we could just use a DOM parser but it's important that we parse them with regex because the user can add classes from JS using `element.classList.add("class")`.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe adding a few details on the what/how will help people come up with a solution for your use-case.

Comment: Your regex matches *any* attribute in quotes e.g. `<div id="div1">`. You should not be trying to parse HTML/JavasScript with regex, use e.g. [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead

Comment: How do you determine that the (possible) contents of the const `z` has anything to do with an HTML class?

Comment: hi guys, so the goal is to take an HTML or JS file and get all the possible HTML classes that can be used, it's easy from the HTML because we could just use a DOM parser but it's important that we parse them with regex because the user can add classes from js like `element.classList.add("class")`

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamírez Why would a parser prevent your user from adding classes? How are they related to each other?

Comment: @InSync sorry for not explaining that, in a later stage of the script, we create a .css file having the classes that were found in the html/js files

Comment: *"it's easy from the HTML because we could just use a DOM parser but it's important that we parse them with regex because the user can add classes from js using"* - what programming language did you actually use to handle this parsing? are you trying to crawl the web pages to get all of the css classes? there are several wrapper for headless browser to enable you parse a live website without being in control of the site directly.

Comment: @BagusTesa hi, thanks for the comment, it's all JavaScript, I'm parsing a local file

Comment: the more i read the question the more i feel it is a sisyphean task.. given it should take account for **entire possibility** of classes the DOM can have - not only what a live and running site would have. there are multiple way to write the class assignment. the template literals as you have mentioned was one of them and people can just write class name using string concatenation, switch case, ifs, choosen from an array of string, etc.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to write class names but at the end of the day they all use quotes, single quotes or backticks so it shouldn't be that hard. I guess I will have to create a new question. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as mentioned by other users, it's a hard task.

I've found a simple regex that could be helpful.

```
/[^<>"'`\s]*[^<>"'`\s:]/g;
```

When using it with the content provided in the original question, it finds any string, and although it includes a lot of false positives (like `html` or `const`), it gives us a grasp of what we're trying to achieve: to get possible class names from a file.

Thank you all for taking your time to answer and comment this question. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In general, avoid use of regex for html, it's not designed for that. If you can parse DOM, do that instead.

You can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect when `class` attribute was changed.

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver((data, _observer) =>
{
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    const item = data[i];
    const element = item.target;

    console.log("Element", element.textContent, 'class changed from', item.oldValue, 'to', element.className);
  }

});

observer.observe(document.getElementById("test"), {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeFilter: ["class"],
  attributeOldValue: true
});



const classes = ["red", "blue", "green"];
function addClass()
{
  const element = test.children[~~(Math.random()*test.children.length)];
  const oldClassName = element.className;
  const newClassName = classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)];
  element.classList.add(newClassName);
  if (newClassName !== oldClassName)
    element.classList.remove(oldClassName);
}
```

```css
.red
{
  background-color: pink;
}
.green
{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.blue
{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="red">one</div>
  <div class="green">two</div>
  <div class="blue">three</div>
</div>
<button onclick="addClass()" type="button">Add class</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not useful to me since I need to work with the file content without reaching the DOM. But I'm leaving this question so future readers with a similar problem can use this answer.  Thank you for your time.